# php and html email forms

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating a website for my church choir in HTML. I have a "contact us" page written in HTML. It has a form for the user to send the choir director an email from the website. I am aware that I have to write the email in php in order for the email to send. Do I need to duplicate the html file and rewrite it in PHP?

```
<form name="Send-mail" action="mailto:email@email.com" method="post">
   <label>Name:</label>
   <input class="nice" name="name" type="text"/>
   <label>Email:</label>
   <input class="nice" name="email" type="text"/>
   <label>Subject:</label>
   <input class="nice" name="subject" type="text"/>`enter code here`
   <label>Message:</label>
   <text-area type="text" name="message"></text-area>
   <input class="centered" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send email"/>  
  </form>
```

I need the server to send the email from the website to the email of our choir director.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create the PHP file where there is an email sending logic,eg: `sendEmail.php`. The form tag would change to:

```
<form name="Send-mail" action="sendEmail.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Would I name the file the same as the html file e.g. index.html --> index.php

Comment: You are free to set any name you like. But if you have an `index.html`, then avoid `index.php`

Answer (score 1):

Below is how you can send the mail in php from form inputs.

```
  <form action="mail.php" method="post">
   <label>Name:</label>
   <input class="nice" name="name" type="text"/>
   <label>Email:</label>
   <input class="nice" name="email" type="text"/>
   <label>Subject:</label>
   <input class="nice" name="subject" type="text"/>`enter code here`
   <label>Message:</label>
   <text-area type="text" name="message"></text-area>
   <input class="centered" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send email"/>  
  </form>
```

You will have to name your php file mail.php like  in case below

**mail.php**

```
<?php
         $to = $_POST['email'];
         $subject = $_POST['subject'];
         $sender = $_POST['name'];

         $message = $_POST['message'];
         $message .= "<h1>This is Message from $sender.</h1>";

         $header = "From:senderemail@somedomain.com \r\n";
         $header .= "Cc:senderemail@somedomain.com \r\n";
         $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

         if( $retval == true ) {
            echo "Message sent successfully...";
         }else {
            echo "Message could not be sent...";
         }
      ?>
```

You will need to ensure that email for this line of code is correctly set.

```
$header = "From:senderemail@somedomain.com \r\n";
         $header .= "Cc:senderemail@somedomain.com \r\n";
```

In otherword, if your site email is **support@hey.com**
Try Replacing it **snderemail@somedomain** and it will work. You can also try the replacement with some other emails like good working **gmail** and let me know what happen. Thanks